# Looping over to cumulate scores in SAS

Tags: sas

Given this dataset in SAS, i would like to calculate:

- the total number of wins obtained for each team
- using do loop to identify how many matches has been performed

```
data array; 
infile datalines dlm=',' firstobs=2;
datalines; 
game,winning_team, points1, loosing_team, points2
May2, Berfield, 12, Jacksons, 10
June3, Jacksons, 23, North, 22
June5, UCI, 12, Jacksons, 10
June23, Nottingham, 12, Jr High, 11
; 
run;
```

May i know how should i start? i used the following code but still can't work

```
array ray(1) game; 
do i=1 to dim(game); 
 i=i+1; 
 output; 
end;
```

Comment: Same person/assignment as here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Data-Analysis-Questions/m-p/782923?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of wins per team it looks like you could just get the frequency counts for variable WINING_TEAM.  The total count will be the number of games played.  No looping is required.

```
proc freq data=array ;
  tables winning_team;
run;
```

PS ARRAY is a strange name for a dataset.  A more descriptive name might be RESULTS since the data appears to list the results of games played.

Answer (score 0):

A win/loss ratio for each team can be computed by `FREQ` if you first pivot each row into two categorical observations.

Example:

```
data season; 
infile datalines dlm=',' ;
length game $10 winning_team $20 points1 8 losing_team $20 points2 8;
input game winning_team points1 losing_team points2;
datalines;
May2, Berfield, 12, Jacksons, 10
June3, Jacksons, 23, North, 22
June5, UCI, 12, Jacksons, 10
June23, Nottingham, 12, Jr High, 11
; 
run;

proc transpose data=season out=winloss(keep=_name_ col1);
  by _all_ notsorted;
  var winning_team losing_team;
run;

proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify winloss;
  rename _name_ = status col1=team;
  label status = ' ';
run;

proc sort data=winloss;
  by team;
proc freq noprint data=winloss;
  by team;
  table status / out=freqs;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will give you those two pieces of information:

```
proc sql;
    select
    count(*) as total_number_of_games
    from array;
    select
    winning_team as team
    ,count(*) as number_of_wins
    from array
    group by 1; 
quit;
```

You don't need to use a do loop as the total number of games played will simply be the number of rows in the table.